# Alternative for scipy.stats.norm.ppf?

Tags: python, scipy

Does anyone know of an alternative Python implementation for scipy.stats.norm.ppf()? I am building an EXE and I would like to avoid adding scipy for this one function.

There is a great alternative for scipy.stats.norm.pdf() here: [Alternative for scipy.stats.norm.pdf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8669235/alternative-for-scipy-stats-norm-pdf)

Answer (score 4):

You can install [`pyerf`](https://pypi.org/project/pyerf/) module. Which is a pure python implementation of `erf` and `erfinv` functions, using the exact same formulas as scipy.

So, sure, it is another module instead of scipy. But it is a pure python one, so no difficulties with dependencies. And a smaller one, since it contains only what your need.

Then, to go from `erfinv` to `norm.ppf`, it is just the classical formula. On wiki, you can see that `x = cdf(y) = 0.5+0.5*erf(y/√2)`, so from there, you can deduce `x-0.5 = 0.5erf(y/√2)` ⇒ `2x-1 = erf(y/√2)` ⇒ `erfinv(2x-1) = y/√2` ⇒ `y=√2×erfinv(2x-1)`

So

```py
import pyerf
import math

def myppf(x):
    return math.sqrt(2)*pyerf.erfinv(2*x-1)
```

Verification

```
>> myppf(0.1)
-1.2815515655446004
>> scipy.stats.norm.ppf(0.1)
-1.2815515655446004
```

### Without pyerf

A little bit more naive, but if performance is not an issue, you can compute erfinv (or directly ppf, see below) by dichotomy from math.erf

```py
import math

def myppf(x):
    a=-9
    b=9
    v2=math.sqrt(2)
    while b-a>1e-9:
        c=(a+b)/2
        r=0.5+0.5*math.erf(c/v2)
        if r>x:
            b=c
        else:
            a=c
    return c
```

```
>>> myppf(0.1)
-1.2815515658003278
```

### Direct polynomial implementation

Or you can implement yourself directly the [polynomial approximation of erfinv](https://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/gilesm/files/gems_erfinv.pdf)

```py
import math

def erfinv(x):
    w = - math.log((1-x)*(1+x))
    if w < 5:
        w = w - 2.5
        p = 2.81022636e-08
        p = 3.43273939e-07 + p*w
        p = -3.5233877e-06 + p*w
        p = -4.39150654e-06 + p*w
        p = 0.00021858087 + p*w
        p = -0.00125372503 + p*w
        p = -0.00417768164 + p*w
        p = 0.246640727 + p*w
        p = 1.50140941 + p*w
    else:
        w = math.sqrt(w) - 3
        p = -0.000200214257
        p = 0.000100950558 + p*w
        p = 0.00134934322 + p*w
        p = -0.00367342844 + p*w
        p = 0.00573950773 + p*w
        p = -0.0076224613 + p*w
        p = 0.00943887047 + p*w
        p = 1.00167406 + p*w
        p = 2.83297682 + p*w
    return p*x

def myppf(x):
    return math.sqrt(2)*erfinv(2*x-1)
```

```
>> myppf(0.1)
-1.2815516851619244
```